# Why can't I use a partition?

Tags: permissions, filesystem

I converted one of my NTFS partitions to ext4 format with the GParted tool. Now, I can not copy, or create, any files on that partition.

Comment: Why can't you "copy create" (copy or create?) files. Any errors? A sudden lack of desire to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of the partition and then delete it with GParted. Then make a partition from the free space however you like.

If this doesn't work check whether your other partitions are working or not. There might a problem with your hard disk.

Comment: Well, that tag's gone. You may want to revisit your answer.

Comment: My answer stays the same, for two reasons. One, the asker hasn't said that he's not installing Ubuntu. And two, my suggestion will probably work the same even if he already has Ubuntu installed (from my experience, I had the same problem multiple times).